# How to have multiple users complete a single form in Google Forms

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Using Google Forms, is there a way to have a user complete a section of a form, share the form and have another user complete another section of the same form, thereby keeping the combined inputs as a unified data set?

Comment: Stick around Kenneth as it might take a while for answers to appear. Welcome on Web Applications !!

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The form owner should set the form to allow users to edit responses. This will give them a link that they could share with others. For more details see [Edit form responses after submitting - Docs editors help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183417?hl=en).

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question

Comment: @EgeAkpinar It does. Have you tried to use the link to edit a form response?